# Fitting Matrix Scale of one Path to another later drawn path

Tags: android, android-layout, graphics

I've got the following problem:
Currently, I draw a picture within a SurfaceView. Moreover, the user is allowed to
draw on this picture. Thereby the draw "figures" are handled as path-objects. In addition, a user can pan as well as zoom the image. The handling of the zoom and pan is done by using a matrix. The picture as well as every path object has the its own matrix.

So, if the user for example started the app, a picture is shown. Then, the user can add one path object after the other and so on. We create for every object a new matrix. For example, if a user zooms in then the path objects as well as the picture are zoomed.

Now my goal is that if a path object is added while the picture is zoomed in or zoomed out, then the path object should be added at the touched position but it should be scaled to the scale of the other already drawn objects. In other, simpler words: If I add a path object it should have the same scale as the already exisitng objects, but it should appear at its new position:

Until now I tried different ways for solving the problem, but nothing did work:

First, of all I scaled the Canvas with one single matrix instead of scaling every path object on its own. But then, the added path objects appeared at a wrong position while the picture was zoomed in.

Next, I tried to get the current scale and afterwards, I scaled the path object when I created it. This did not work either. For non of the methodes preScale,postScale,setScale ... Either the whole path was wrong or it appeared again at a wrong position.

Does anyone know a solution?